# Oracle SQL: Obtain count of distinct column values based on another column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is a sample data to explain my case,

CompanyInfo:

```
Name,   Company, Location,   Completed,  Pending
Andy      AA        Home        4         2
Jim       AA        Office      3         3
Dahli     AA        Home        4         2
Monica    AA        Home        4         2
Chandler  AA    Home-Office     1         0
Ashley    AA    Home-Office     1         0
```

The last three columns have duplicated information and I am trying to obtain count of location, completed and pending which are bound to each other. So the output would look something like below,

```
   Company, Count(Locations), Count( Completed+Pending > 0),
    AA            3                   3
```

Why Count( Completed+Pending > 0)  is 3? there are just three unique combinations of Home, Office and home-office columns where sum of completed+pending is > 0.

I did try below, but it gives me **(AA, 3, 6)** since it is processing all the 6 rows to obtain the count.

```
select Company, 
       count(distinct Location),
        SUM (
               CASE
                  WHEN (Completed + Pending) > 0 THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
               END)
               AS Total
       From CompanyInfo
       group by Company;
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you provide clearer explanation and sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you want a conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
select Company, 
       count(distinct Location),
       count(distinct case when Completed + Pending > 0 then location end)
from CompanyInfo
group by Company;
```

Comment: Thank you for the sql but if Home and Office have the same values. 
Home  4    2
Office  4    2

In which case the count should be 2, but the above SQL would result in 1.

Comment: @vick_4444 . . . No.  This is counting distinct values of *location*, which appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: "count(distinct Completed + Pending > 0 then location end)" is this syntax for some specific version of Oracle SQL Or does it need to be put inside a CASE statement? My toad query browser shows syntax error near ">" and prompts for a closing brace.

Comment: @vick_4444 - it's missing part of the case - `count(distinct case when Completed + Pending > 0 then location end)`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=767fc33531c731ef8ff09fc09437681f)

Comment: Thank you very much @GordonLinoff, it works. I missed noticing the 'then location' which would form a unique combination with other two columns, a very nice trick!.